# What is the third argument to `ts.createSourceFile()` in the typescript API for?

Tags: typescript

I'm using the typescript API to implement a TS compiler based on https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API (the only docs other than the source AFAICT)

The third argument of `createSourceFile` takes a `ScriptTarget` enum but I'm not sure what it's supposed to be for. I'm transpiling to ES5 and specify this in the options passed to `ts.createProgram`. AFAICT it doesn't matter whether I pass `Latest` or `ES5` to `createSourceFile`.

Comment: Are you using ECMA features that are only available after ES5? If not, there shouldn't be a difference between `ES5` and `Latest`. If you are, they will be replaced with ES5-compatable functionality (e.g. arrow functions will be converted to function definitions).

Comment: @DM modern JS constructs seem to successfully transpile to ES5 regardless of what I pass to `createSourceFile`

Comment: My only guess then is that `createProgram` is setting the max-allowed ECMA version. If you set that to `ES6` or `ESNext` then maybe you'd see a difference between passing `ES5` and `Latest`. That's speculation on my part, though.